# Pre-loading audio buffers - what is reasonable and reliable?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I am converting an audio signal processing application from Win XP to Win 7 (at least). You can imagine it is a sonar application - a signal is generated and sent out, and a related/modified signal is read back in. The application wants exclusive use of the audio hardware, and cannot afford glitches - we don't want to read headlines like "Windows beep causes missile launch".

Looking at the Windows SDK audio samples, the most relevant one to my case is the **RenderExclusiveEventDriven** example. Outside the audio engine, it prepares 10 seconds of audio to play, which provides it in 10ms chunks to the rendering engine via an `IAudioRenderClient` object's `GetBuffer()` and `ReleaseBuffer()`. It first uses these functions to pre-load a single 10ms chunk of audio, then relies on regular 10ms events to load subsequent chunks.

Hopefully this means there will always be 10-20ms of audio data buffered. How reliable (i.e. glitch-free) should we expect this to be on reasonably modern hardware (less than 18months old)?

Previously, one readily could pre-load at least half a second worth of audio into via the `waveXXX()` API, so that if Windows got busy elsewhere, audio continuity was less likely to be affected. 500ms seems like a lot safer margin than 10-20ms... but if you want both event-driven and exclusive-mode, the `IAudioRenderClient` documentation doesn't exactly make it clear if it is or is not possible to pre-load more than a single `IAudioRenderClient` buffer worth.

Can anyone confirm if more extensive pre-loading is still possible? Is it recommended, discouraged or neither?

Comment: `IAudioRenderClient` and the entire WASAPI is Win Vista+; exclusive streams with WASAPI overall is a good approach (except OS version notice). With exclusive streams you might be good with pre-loading 10-20 ms of data (some reports were that 5 ms is OK), without exclusivity you will have to pre-load at least 80-100 ms so that data could be on time going through mixing layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about launching missiles, I don't think you should be using Windows or any other non Real-Time operating system.

That said, we are working on another application that consumes a much higher bandwidth of data (400 MB/s continuously for hours or more). We have seen glitches where the operating system becomes unresponsive for up to 5 seconds, so we have large buffers on the data acquisition hardware.

Comment: I guess those glitches would be because of storage IO which is always the weakest link in the chain.

Comment: I'm not actually worried about launching missiles - it's a kind of metaphor for how mission-critical this app is to the business. I am also happy to work within the non real-time limitations of Windows for the other advantages it brings... which seems to be your situation too :-)

Comment: We are using Linux CentOS... which isn't any better than Windows for RTOS-ness.

Comment: @ddriver - We don't do any file IO. The glitches were due to TLB misses.

Answer (score 1):

Like with everything else in computing, the wider you go you:

- increase throughput
- increase latency

I'd say 512 samples buffer is the minimum typically used for non-demanding latency wise applications. I've seen up to 4k buffers. Memory use wise that's still pretty much nothing for contemporary devices - a mere 8 kilobytes of memory per channel for 16 bit audio. You have better playback stability and lower waste of CPU cycles. For audio applications that means you can process more tracks with more DSP before audio begins skipping.

On the other end - I've seen only a few professional audio interfaces, which could handle 32 sample buffers. Most are able to achieve 128 samples, naturally you are still limited to lower channel and effect count, even with professional hardware you increase buffering as your project gets larger, lower it back and disable tracks or effects when you need "real time" to capture a performance. In terms of lowest possible latency actually the same box is capable of achieving lower latency with Linux and a custom real time kernel than on Windows where you are not allowed to do such things. Keep in mind a 64 sample buffer might sound like 8 msec of latency in theory, but in reality it is more like double - because you have both input and output latency plus the processing latency.

For a music player where latency is not an issue you are perfectly fine with a larger buffer, for stuff like games you need to keep it lower for the sake of still having a degree of synchronization between what's going on visually and the sound - you simply cannot have your sound lag half a second behind the action, for music performance capturing together with already recorded material you need to have latency low. You should never go above what your use case requires, because a small buffer will needlessly add to CPU use and the odds of getting audio drop outs. **4k buffering for an audio player is just fine if you can live with half a second of latency between the moment you hit play and the moment you hear the song starting**.

I've done a "kind of a hybrid" solution in my DAW project - since I wanted to employ GPGPU for its tremendous performance relative to the CPU I've split the work internally with two processing paths - 64 samples buffer for real time audio which is processed on the CPU, and another considerably wider buffer size for the data which is processed by the GPU. Naturally, they both come out through the "CPU buffer" for the sake of being synchronized perfectly, but the GPU path is "processed in advance" thus allowing higher throughput for already recorded data, and keeping CPU use lower so the real time audio is more reliable. I am honestly surprised professional DAW software hasn't taken this path yet, but not too much, knowing how much money the big fishes of the industry make on hardware that is much less powerful than a modern midrange GPU. They've been claiming that "latency is too much with GPUs" ever since Cuda and OpenCL came out, but with pre-buffering and pre-processing that is really not an issue for data which is already recorded, and increases the size of a project which the DAW can handle tremendously.

Comment: Thanks - I am now looking into a sort of hybrid too - the old app used 512 sample buffers for both output and input to make it easier to relate the two. The input needs to be processed in as close to real time as possible (~10ms period). The old app preloaded multiple buffers to the waveOut() side to help maintain signal continuity, but I guess there is no need to keep the input and output buffer sizes the same so long as I can relate the two streams. So I'll increase the output buffer size independently until I get a reliable result.

Comment: If you are aiming for low latencies, your best bet on windows is ASIO - I suggest building and using RTAudio - which supports ASIO on top of a few other APIs, plus it will make your life easier if you decide to migrate your application to other platforms - the same code will work with different audio APIs on different platforms.

Comment: Also, strongly suggest to use OpenCL for the processing part - it has the great advantage of being able to quickly compile kernels on the go, allowing to generate long processing chains in a single kernel, eliminating a lot of overhead, plus the same kernels can be ran on either the CPU or GPU depending on your latency requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can preload a larger amount of data.

This [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370844(v=vs.85).aspx) uses a call to `GetDevicePeriod` to return the minimum service interval for the device (in nano seconds) and then passes that value along to `Initialize`. You can pass a larger value if you wish.

The down side to increasing the period is that you're increasing the latency. If you are just playing a waveform back and aren't planning on making changes on the fly then this is not a problem. But if you had a sine generator for example, then the increased latency means that it would take longer for you to hear a change in frequency or amplitude.

Whether or not you have drop outs depends on a number of things. Are you setting thread priorities appropriately? How small is the buffer? How much CPU are you using preparing your samples? In general though, a modern CPU can handle a pretty low-latency. For comparison, ASIO audio devices run perfectly fine at 96kHz with a 2048 sample buffer (20 milliseconds) with multiple channels - no problem. ASIO uses a similar double buffering scheme.

Comment: Thanks - useful answer... which doesn't quite answer the bit I really wanted, because I appear to have edited it out before I submitted the question (D'oh!). Under waveXXX() you could have a multiple buffering scheme - pre-load lots of buffers. Under WASAPI, and in exclusive mode/event-drive where buffer duration and periodicity are equal, is double-buffering (only) enforced... or can you pre-load multiple buffers before starting the render client? I'm about to test it - you may be able to edit your answer before I find out :-)

Comment: it is double buffering only for exclusive mode for sure - I'm not sure about shared mode. Still if you choose a sufficient buffer size in the first place it isn't going to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to be a comment, so it may as well be an answer (with qualifications).

Although it was edited out of final form of the question I submitted, what I had intended by "more extensive pre-loading" was not about the size of buffers used, so much as the number of buffers used. The (somewhat unexpected) answers that resulted all helped widen my understanding.

But I was curious. In the old `waveXXX()` world, it was possible to "pre-load" multiple buffers via `waveOutPrepareHeader()` and `waveOutWrite()` calls, the first `waveOutWrite()` of which would start playback. My old app "pre-loaded" 60 buffers out of a set of 64 in one burst, each with 512 samples played at 48kHz, creating over 600ms of buffering in a system with a cycle of 10.66ms.

Using multiple `IAudioRenderClient::GetBuffer()` and `IAudioRenderClient::ReleaseBuffer()` calls prior to `IAudioCient::Start()` in the WASAPI world, it appears that the same is still possible... at least on my (very ordinary) hardware, and without extensive testing (yet). This is despite the documentation strongly suggesting that exclusive, event-driven audio is strictly a double-buffering system.

I don't know that anyone should set out to exploit this by design, but I thought I'd point out that it may be supported.